# (python) functions with variable arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

How do I get the following code to work so the functions are executed on the player scores separately and allow them to accumulate?(btw, I'm very new to python so don't judge)

```
player_1_score=0
player_2_score=0
def six(score):
    print('you rolled a 6')
    print('''
 -------
| o   o |
| o   o |
| o   o |
 -------   ''')
    score+=6

def five(score):
     print('you rolled a 5')
     print('''
 -------
| o   o |
|   o   |
| o   o |
 -------    ''')
     score+=5

#for player1
five(player_1_score)
six(player_1_score)
print('p1 score:',int(player_1_score))

#for player2
five(player_2_score)
six(player_2_score)
print('p2 score:',int(player_1_score))
```

the code should display: 11 for player scores when run but displays 0 instead.

Comment: When your function modifies 'score' it is modifying a local copy in the function.  The outer variable 'player_1_score' does not see the change.  You need to return the modified score from the function so the calling script can see it. Add 'return score' as the last line in functions 'five' and 'six'.  Call then with: player_1_score = five(player_1_score).  Then you've modified player_1_score in the calling script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the new score from each function:

```
def six(score):
    print('you rolled a 6')
    print('''
 -------
| o   o |
| o   o |
| o   o |
 -------   ''')
    score += 6
    return score
```

But the call sites need to be like this:

```
player_1_score = five(player_1_score)
```

Compulsory link to [names](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

You could update the scores separately, i.e. not in the "roll dice" functions. I think it is more readable in this phase. Later, when you advance in learning Python, you will probably solve the problem differently, perhaps with a `Player` class and a mapping (number 1 to 6) --> (dice face as a string).

```
def six():
    print('you rolled a 6')
    print('''\
 -------
| o   o |
| o   o |
| o   o |
 -------   ''')
    return 6

def five():
    print('you rolled a 5')
    print('''\
 -------
| o   o |
|   o   |
| o   o |
 -------    ''')
    return 5

player_1_score = 0
player_2_score = 0

#for player1
player_1_score += five()
player_1_score += six()

#for player2
player_2_score += five() + six()

print('scores:', player_1_score, player_2_score)
```

Note: I added a continuation backslash to the `print('''\`) statement to get rid of the blank line. I like it better but you may prefer the blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change player's score but you are not modifying it either. You are sending player's score but if you change score in your functions (`six` and `five`), you are **not** modifying original score. If you want to modify original score, you can return `score` from your functions and assign it to your player's scores. For example:

```
def five(score):
     print('you rolled a 5')
     print('''
 -------
| o   o |
|   o   |
| o   o |
 -------    ''')
     score+=5
     return score

#for player1
player_1_score=five(player_1_score)
print('p1 score:',int(player_1_score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an argument to the `score` parameter for `five(score)` and `six(score)` creates a `score` variable within the scope of each function. So when the program calls `five(player_1_score)`, the value of `player_1_score` is copied to `score`. You'll need to

1. Modify each of your functions to return the `score` value
2. Assign the output of each function to each outer scope variable

```
player_1_score=0
player_2_score=0
def six(score):
    print('you rolled a 6')
    print('''
 -------
| o   o |
| o   o |
| o   o |
 -------   ''')
    score+=6
    return score

def five(score):
     print('you rolled a 5')
     print('''
 -------
| o   o |
|   o   |
| o   o |
 -------    ''')
     score += 5
     return score


#for player1
player_1_score = five(player_1_score)
player_1_score = six(player_1_score)
print('p1 score:',int(player_1_score))

#for player2
player_2_score = five(player_2_score)
player_2_score = six(player_2_score)
print('p2 score:',int(player_2_score))
```